# How to configure asp.net MVC project in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, configuration

When I run project in IIS, after displaying home page it will not allow to redirect on any other page. It gives Page could not found error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On IIS 6 you may need to [register a mapping](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) in order to associate the ASP.NET ISAPI module with an extension or if you would like to have extensionless URLs you may take a look at this [article](http://elitebrains.com/blogs/view/asp-net/4/iis-6-and-asp-net-mvc-extensionless-urls-that-work-even-in-postbacks).